# Function template overload puzzle

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, overloading

I have a class and a class template

```
class promise;

template <class... Ts>
class typed_promise;
```

I intend to design a cast utility to cast between them

```
template <class... Ts>
typed_promise<Ts...> promise_cast(promise x);

template <class... Ts>
promise promise_cast(typed_promise<Ts...> x);
```

So, you can do the following cast

```
promise pms;
typed_promise<int, int> typed_pms;
auto typed_pms2 = promise_cast<int, int>(pms);
auto pms2 = promise_cast(typed_pms);
```

I also want to support usage like

```
auto typed_pms2 = promise_cast<typed_promise<int, int>>(pms);
```

which is equivalent to

```
auto typed_pms2 = promise_cast<int, int>(pms);
```

Since C++ does not allow partial function template specialization, is it possible to achieve what I want? If possible, how should I do it?

Comment: "does not allow" is wrong. "Does not directly support" is more like it. But I don't see the *technical* problem here, you have two different overloads. Just changing the pure declarations to definitions, [the code works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9c7c7415e98d6a4).

Comment: Voted to close as lacking example of the problem.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That would make a `typed_promise<typed_promise<int, int>>`.

Comment: This somewhat depends on what you need to do. Do you need access to `Ts...` inside the `promise_cast` implementation?

Comment: If `promise` is made base of `typed_promise`, the casting problem would be solved by natural upcast and `static_cast`

Comment: @T.C. Yes. `Ts...` will be used to determine the return type.

Comment: @Lingxi Of course it's needed in the return type; anywhere else?

Comment: The question appears to be about supporting the template argument list as specifically `promise_cast<typed_promise<int, int>>` to call the `promise_cast(promise x)` overload. Please clarify the post and focus on this issue, and also use a better title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch to a class template that you can partially specialize.

```
template<class... Ts>
struct promise_cast_impl {
    static typed_promise<Ts...> do_cast(promise) {
        // do stuff
    }
};

template<class... Ts>
struct promise_cast_impl<typed_promise<Ts...>> {
    static typed_promise<Ts...> do_cast(promise p){
        return promise_cast_impl<Ts...>::do_cast(std::move(p));
    }
};

template<class... Ts>
auto promise_cast(promise x) 
     -> decltype(promise_cast_impl<Ts...>::do_cast(std::move(x))){
    return promise_cast_impl<Ts...>::do_cast(std::move(x));
}
```

---

If you don't use `Ts...` anywhere else, you can simplify this slightly by writing a metafunction that just computes the return type from `Ts...`.

Comment: Yes. This solves my problem :-) Just delegate the function call to a class template which I can partial specialize.

Answer (score 3):

When overloading becomes tricky, you should consider the alternative of not overloading at all.

Give the functions different names, perhaps `add_promise_type` and `erase_promise_type`. Then no "partial specialization" is needed.

```
template <class... Ts>
typed_promise<Ts...> add_promise_type(promise x);

template <class... Ts>
promise erase_promise_type(typed_promise<Ts...> x);
```

It's often tempting to emulate typecasting, but it's a minefield of [XY problems](http://xyproblem.info/). You'll be happier with a simpler solution, which is actually more specific to the task at hand.